# Is there any way to phisically debug android studio app through remote desktop?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, adb

I'm working with a phisical machine in my office, but I'm connected there by Remote Desktop.

Can I connect my  android device to my home machine and debug my app with android studio installed in my office machine?

I'm connected vía VPN to the office network, and Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect my machine. Both machines are Windows 10. I have shared all usb, but remote machine doesn't see my phone.

Android device has enabled usb debugging, and local android studio can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssh` tunnel to achieve that.
This script is an example of how it can be done (*perhaps you need some tweaks on windows*): [remote_setup.sh](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/tools/android/adb_remote_setup.sh)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is for linux. My both machines are Windows, and are bussiness machines, I can not tweaking Windows, I'm not admin.